# Understanding Conflict Between Data Wrappers, Graphics Directives, and Options for Plots

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, visualization, style

I have two related questions. First, I am trying to find out what ways I can change a single point in a plot using data wrappers that are not overwritten by other plot options (like `PlotMarkers`).

The following code succeeds in making red the point I want to be red.

```
ListLinePlot3D[{{2.1, Style[2.9, Red], 2.8, 1.9}, {2.2, 2.7, 1.1, 
   2.2}, {2.3, 1.7, 2.3, 1.7}}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 0.03}]
```

[image: 1]

Now, I want the same single point to be bigger, but this seems to be more difficult for reasons I do not understand, as you can see in my following two attempts...

- using `PointSize`

```
ListLinePlot3D[{{2.1, Style[2.9, Red, PointSize[0.1]], 2.8, 
   1.9}, {2.2, 2.7, 1.1, 2.2}, {2.3, 1.7, 2.3, 1.7}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 0.03}]
```

- using a number

```
ListLinePlot3D[{{2.1, Style[2.9, Red, 1], 2.8, 
   1.9}, {2.2, 2.7, 1.1, 2.2}, {2.3, 1.7, 2.3, 1.7}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 0.03}]
```

Both give the same "default" output below.
[image: 2]

And this leads me to my second question. Notice the point is no longer red even though I still have it specified, as if my attempts at the specification of size prohibits the specification that the point be red, and no error is thrown.

Something even more strange occurs when I remove the specification of color. With `PointSize`, the point turns black, not the default blue, and with a number, the point disappears entirely.

- using `PointSize`

```
ListLinePlot3D[{{2.1, Style[2.9, PointSize[0.1]], 2.8, 1.9}, {2.2, 
   2.7, 1.1, 2.2}, {2.3, 1.7, 2.3, 1.7}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 0.03}]
```

[image: 3]

- using a number

```
ListLinePlot3D[{{2.1, Style[2.9, 2], 2.8, 1.9}, {2.2, 2.7, 1.1, 
   2.2}, {2.3, 1.7, 2.3, 1.7}}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 0.03}]
```

[image: 4]

What's going on here?

### Addendum

On a related note, I find this annoying.

The code

```
ListLinePlot3D[{{2.1, Style[2.9], 2.8, 1.9}, {2.2, 2.7, 1.1, 
   2.2}, {2.3, 1.7, 2.3, 1.7}}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 0.03}]
```

and

```
ListLinePlot3D[{{2.1, Style[2.9, Automatic], 2.8, 1.9}, {2.2, 2.7, 
   1.1, 2.2}, {2.3, 1.7, 2.3, 1.7}}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 0.03}]
```

do not give the same output. The second one colors the point black for some reason.

### Related Questions

[Preserving Automatic PlotMarker Styles in Plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/266749/12697)

Answer (score 3):

In this specific case the problem seems to be that the markers are generated using `Point` which has only `VertexColors` and `VertexNormals` as options. If one inspects the expression generated by the code examples it becomes clear that only under certain circumstances the color gets piped through correctly. `Style[2.9, 2]` leads to `VertexColors->2` which causes the point to vanish and `Style[2.9, PointSize[0.05]]` leads to `VertexColors->PointSize[0.05]` where `PointSize[0.05]` somehow gets interpreted as black the same as `Style[2.9, Automatic]`.

It does not seem possible to specify the point size inside `Point` but rather in typical Mathematica graphics fashion by prepending it: *e.g.* `...PointSize[0.05],Point[...],...`. So one dirty hack to style individual points is marking them in code with *e.g.* `Style[...,"s1"]` and then use a rule to set the desired style once explicit code for the graphics is already generated:

```
ListLinePlot3D[{{2.1, Style[2.9, "s1"], 2.8, 1.9}, {2.2, 2.7, 1.1, 
    2.2}, {2.3, 1.7, 2.3, 1.7}}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 0.03}];
% /. Point[y_, VertexColors -> "s1"] :> {PointSize[.05], 
   Point[y, VertexColors -> Red]}
```

resulting in

> [image: Plot]

Granted this is a bit clumsy but at least it works. In fact manipulating plots or graphics in Mathematica using such rules is often the easiest solution for somewhat specialized applications like this one.

Comment: If markers are generated using `Point`, then it's not the same `Point` used in `Graphics3D`. Compare `ListLinePlot3D[{{2.1, Style[2.9, Automatic], 2.8, 1.9}, {2.2, 2.7, 
   Style[1.1, Automatic], 2.2}, {2.3, 1.7, Style[2.3, Automatic], 
   1.7}}, PlotMarkers -> {Point[{0, 0, 0}], 100}]` with `ListLinePlot3D[{{2.1, Style[2.9, Automatic], 2.8, 1.9}, {2.2, 2.7, 
   Style[1.1, Automatic], 2.2}, {2.3, 1.7, Style[2.3, Automatic], 
   1.7}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> 
  Graphics3D[Point[{0, 0, 0}], Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 100]]`. (Referencing https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/266749/12697)